# In Asp.Net Listview Itemtemplate, adding onclick="EditCompany(this) is always passing the first row in resultset

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview

I am working on Asp.Net webforms application with framework 4.1. 
I am using Listview in one of the pages. I created a popup window to showup when the user clicks on the Edit button within the item template
The code for that functionality

```
 <asp:ListView ID="LstVwCompanies" runat="server" DataKeyNames="cityID" DataSourceID="EntDataSrcCompanieslist">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
        <td style="width:50px;">
            <img id="Editcomp" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Edit" src="images/edit.png" onclick="EditCompany(this);" /> 
            <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
         </td>
         <td>
           <span id="cityID" style="visibility:hidden;"><%# Eval("cityID") %></span>
           <span id="company"><%# Eval("companyName") %></span>
         </td>
```

The Editcomp click event handler onclick="EditCompany(this) is always passing the first row in resultset.
If my result set had 3 rows and the user clicks on 3rd row, we were getting the 1st row from the list view.
The javascript code is as follows

```
function EditCompany() {
//row = $("#Editcomp").parent().parent();
 //row1 = $("#btnEdit").parent();
    cityID = $("#cityID", row).text();
    country = $("#country", row).text();
    name = $("#company", row).text();
    desc = $("#description", row).text();
    DisplayCompany();
    return false;
}

function DisplayCompany() {
    $("#spnCityIDEd").text(cityID);
    $("#spnCountry").text(country);
    $("#spnCity").val(name);
    $("#editForm").show();
}
```

The Edit dialog declaration is

```
  <%--Popup Edit Window--%>
                          <div id="editForm" class="editForm">
                               <table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" >
                                  <tr class="headerRow">
                                      <td></td>
                                     <td style="align-content:center;width:300px; font-weight:bold;">Edit Company</td>
                                     <td style="text-align: right;">
                                        <%--<a onclick="CloseEditCompanyDialog();" style="cursor: pointer;">Close</a>--%>
                                     </td>
                                  </tr> 
                                  <tr>
                                     <td></td>
                                     <td><span id="spnCityIDEd" style="visibility:hidden;"></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                     <td>Country:</td>
                                     <td><span id="spnCountry"></span></td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                     <td>City:</td>
                                     <td><span id="spnCity"></span>
                                       <%--  <span id="spnCityID" style="visibility:hidden;"></span>--%>
                                     </td>

                                  </tr>
```

.
I initially thought this might have been caused by the Listview using the datasource using EnterpriseDatasource. So I changed it to bind the listview manually through the code. 
Changed it from

```
DataKeyNames="cityID" DataSourceID="EntDataSrcCompanieslist"
```

to

```
 database dbAdmin = new database();
        String strSQL;
        dbAdmin.dbConnect();
        strSQL = "SELECT * from table where ID=" + field.SelectedValue;
        SqlDataReader rd = dbAdmin.sqlOpen(strSQL);
        LstVwCompanies.DataSource = rd;
        LstVwCompanies.DataBind();
```

Comment: What is "row" in EditCompany function ?And from where you get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clicking on `img` and passing that img reference to function but your spans from where you are getting values is in row so you need to get row.Here is how you can get the row and than get the values.

You will pass img to function and in function you will get the row by using below code.

```
var row = $(img).closest("tr");
OR
var row = $(img).parent().parent();
```

You can use anyone of these.

```
function EditCompany(img) {
var row = $(img).closest("tr");
cityID = $("#cityID", row).text();
country = $("#country", row).text();
name = $("#company", row).text();
desc = $("#description", row).text();
DisplayCompany();
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mairaj, I have changed the code to following function EditCompany() {
    //row = $("#EditButton").parent().parent();
    //row = $("#btnEdit").parent().parent();
    var row = $("#btnEdit").closest("tr");
    cityID = $("#cityID", row).text(); // This was giving the cityId =1 (row 1)
    var img = $("#btnEdit");
    var row = $("#btnEdit").parent.parent;
    cityID = $("#cityID", row).text();  //This was also giving row 1.

Comment: I changed the code to following function. The value of cityID is always showing as 1, irrespective of the row clicked.  EditCompany() {
    var row = $("#btnEdit").closest("tr");
    cityID = $("#cityID", row).text();
    var img = $("#btnEdit");
    var row = img.parent.parent;
    cityID = $("#cityID", row).text();
    //var row = $("#btnEdit").closest("tr");
    var row1 = img.closest("tr");
    cityID = $("#cityID", row1).text();

Comment: You are still not passing img to function just paste my code and it should work.

Comment: Where is your btnEdit ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75237/discussion-between-nate-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Comment: @Nate are you facing any issue ?

Comment: Yes, It is working when I run the application within Visual Studio. When I deployed the application to IIS on a windows server, it is showing the first record. Used chrome and the structure of the elements was exactly the same

Comment: Check the id of your elements it may be changing on server.You can check it from browser by inspect element.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Mairaj. It was caching issue.